# SSAS cube does not SUM identical records in fact table

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

My fact/measures table contains two identical records (all columns contain same data).

When I process the cube it appears that it only sums up one of the two records.
So instead of getting the result 100 that I expected, I get 50 units for 2015/01/01.

It seems like the cube performs something like a `group by` function on the measures when processing resulting in getting only 1 line from the two identical records.

Fact Table:

```
Code   name       date       units
----------------------------------
 1     productA   20150101    50
 1     productA   20150101    50
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the fact\dimension design point of view you should have only distinct combinations of dimension keys in your fact table. So, for example in your case, if

- `Code` column is a key to `Codes` dimension,
- `Name` column is a key
  to `Products` dimension and
- `Date` column is a key to `Date`
  dimension and
- `Units` is a numeric fact value

then you should have distinct dimension keys combinations (Code, Name, Date) and preaggregated to this level of granularity, numeric `unit` values.

So, if in your case you need to have both these rows (they are not duplicates by business point of view) it looks like you should change the granularity level of this fact table, or in another words, add one more dimension attribute (key) to your fact table, which will distinguish these rows, by some hidden (for now) dimension, for example `Operator`. After this manipulation your fact table might look something like this

```
Code  Operator   name       date        units
1     1          productA   20150101    50
1     2          productA   20150101    50
```